# Google Sheets onEdit function jumping to A1 cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm just starting with javascript and trying to make some checkboxes into radio buttons in Google Sheets.
It successfully turns off the appropriate checkboxes when one is turned on, but after the script runs the active cell always resets to the A1 cell in the 'Home' sheet, even if the edit was to a different sheet.

I'm lost as to why this is happening. I would like the original sheet & cell the user was on to remain activated after the script runs.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var eSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var eRange = e.range;
  if ((eSheet.getSheetName() == "Home") && (e.range.rowStart == 8) && (e.range.columnStart > 2) && (e.range.columnStart < 8) && (e.value == "TRUE")) {

    // Makes sure no other checkboxes are on
    for (var i = 3; i < 8; i++) {
      if (i == e.range.columnStart) continue;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, i).setValue(false);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try getting the active spreadsheet first, calling it just once.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  let eSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if ((eSheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Home") && (e.value == "TRUE") && (e.range.columnStart > 2) && (e.range.columnStart < 8) && (e.range.rowStart == 8)) {
    // Makes sure no other checkboxes are on
    for (var i = 3; i < 8; i++) {
      if (i == e.range.columnStart) continue;
      eSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, i).setValue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

It does not change the cursor from the active cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is happening but what about if you try this:

Since you are using the event object, you don't need to use `getActiveSheet()`. Try using `e.range.getSheet()`.